# JSF analog clock

Tags: jsf, time

I am new to JSF. I am trying to display an analog clock on one of my .xhtml pages. I'd like it to not rely on anything but HTML, CSS, and/or PrimeFaces. Nowhere I have looked I could find an easy-fix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that won't be an "easy-fix", and to my knowledge there isn't anything like it available in any JSF component library.

As it's a very specific need, it's probably not worthy of all the work it would need to be maintained in a component library like PrimeFaces.

But you will have better luck if you decide to use a Javascript library like [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/). They actually have a working [analog clock in the demo](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/clock/demo.html), with moveable hands. :)

Comment: my problem with javascript is that I have been trying to use it but I can't seem to manage to get it to work. I guess I'll just have to look into it more to see if maybe I am doing something wrong.